# foreach get one value

Tags: php, foreach, echo

When I do var_dump($punkty); 
I got something like this:

```
array(1) 
{ 
[0]=> array(4) 
    { 
    ["id"]=> string(2) "28" 
    ["mapa"]=> string(97) "a:3s:3:"lat";s:17:"49.21103723075132";s:3:"lng";s:18:"22.330280542373657";s:4:"zoom";s:2:"17";}" 
    ["miasto"]=> string(5) "Cisna" 
    ["nazwa_obiektu"]=> string(44) "Cisna - noclegi u Mirosławy w Bieszczadach" 
    }
}
```

When i do:

```
foreach ($punkty['mapa'] as $item)
        {
        echo $item;
        }
```

I get

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
foreach($punkty as $item) {
    echo $item['mapa'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mapa is at `$punkty[0]['mapa']`, not at `$punkty['mapa']`.

Answer (score 0):

But don't forget to verify your $punkty is not empty, for don't have an other error :-) , for sample:

```
if (isset($punkty )){
    foreach($punkty as $item){
        echo $item[0]['mapa'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$punkty['mapa'] is not an array in your case but the string you can only pass arrays or objects who implements the iterator to foreach loop.